# At runtime replace enum values in C# file in dll

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, enums

I have written a dll in C# which has five `.cs` files. `ControlsOnForm.cs` has a public enum defined in it.

```
public enum FormControls {
   Button,
   Label,
   DataGrid,
   TextBox
}
```

Now, I'm using this dll in a Windows app which is shown in attached Image1 and when I click `Generate` button it generates the `ControlsOnForm.cs` C# file which is same as the enum in dll.

[image]

Now how do I refer/use this dynamically generated C# file with enum values in dll.
Or in another words the enum values in `ControlsOnForm.cs` of dll should get replaced with the newly generated C# file's enum values.

Thanks,

Comment: You could perhaps use the CSharpCodeProvider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx), though I *highly* suspect that building dynamic code probably isn't the way to go here.  Separating the static aspects from the data which drives them and storing that data in a database is probably going to be a lot easier.

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to achieve by this? Show the code you think you want to generate, and what you propose to do with it once you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is trivial to get your code to generate a cs file. I suspect what you then want to do is run the resulting code. That step is highly difficult and there are many things you need to understand in terms of the limitation.

However as another user has commented, it sounds like what you want to change is data, and not code.

You should understand the distinction between hardware, firmware, code, configuration and data. The lines are much more blurred than you might first think. But at the end of the day, each is a step in a continuum of changeability. For your purpose, code should be the thing that changes the least often. This in our tool chain it is the hardest to change. Remember at the end of the day everything is ones and zeros... and your data should also change how your program works.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are a collection of named constants.  In the same sense that you cannot change a constant, you cannot change an enum (at least without jumping through a ton of hoops).

What you really want to do here is use an external dataset, be it a datatable, an XML configuration file, etc.

On a side note, you would probably want to create an enum outside of a form, but in the same namespace.  You can add a module to a project and drop all your enums in there.

From MSDN:

> The enum keyword is used to declare an enumeration, a distinct type
>   that consists of a set of **named constants** called the enumerator
>   list.
>
> Usually it is best to define an enum directly within a namespace so
>   that all classes in the namespace can access it with equal
>   convenience. However, an enum can also be nested within a class or
>   struct.

Reference: [MSDN Enum Entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)